# How to change billing account from individual to business in AdMob

Tags: admob

I've a problem I can't solve: I need to change billing account from individual to business in AdMob. But I don't found any provision for that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found the solution?

Comment: I am still trying but not got any solution.

Comment: It looks like that we have to close the individual account, then open a new business account.  This is really unfortunate.

Comment: @minfo Have you found any solution now?

Comment: No, created new one. @Pavitra

Answer (score 0):

You can change account type from the link below!

https://support.google.com/admob/contact/change_account

Comment: Hey, this link doesn't work anymore. Do you have an alternative link?